# Como elimino valores de un arreglo en c++?

Tags: c++, array

mi duda esta al momento de eliminar valores de un arreglo y recorrer puesto que no borra, aqui esta parte de mi codigo (encuentro la posicion a eliminar pero no no hace)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int contador;
class Cliente //Clase
{
    char nombre[5][10]; //atributos de la clase
    char apellido[5][10];
     float estatura[5];
    int edad[5];
    char situacion_civil[5][10];


    //Metodos
    public:
        void alta();
        void consulta_uno();
        void consulta_general();
        void baja();
        void modificar();

};

 void Cliente::alta()
 {
    system("cls");
    cout<<"//////////////ALTA/////////////////////";
    string nombre_buscado;
    string apellido_buscado;
    if(contador>=5)
    {
        cout<<"La lista esta llena";
    }
    else
    {


cout<<"    \nIngrese el nombre y apellido del cliente:";cin >> nombre_buscado>>apellido_buscado;
int i;
for( i=0; i<contador; i++ )
{
  if( nombre[i] == nombre_buscado && apellido[i] == apellido_buscado )
    break;
}

if( i < contador )
{


    cout<<"El usuario ya esta registrado...";
  // Ya has encontrado el registro que buscas
  // ...


}
else
{ 
 //No esta en la lista
 cout<<"   El usuario:"<<nombre_buscado<<" "<<apellido_buscado<<" No esta en la lista, favor de capturar."<<endl;
 cout<<"   Ingrese el nombre y apellido:";cin>>nombre[i]>>apellido[i];
 cout<<"   Ingrese la estatura:";cin>>estatura[i];
cout<<"    Ingrese la situacion civil del cliente :";cin>>situacion_civil[i];
cout<<"    Ingrese la edad:          ";cin>>edad[i];cout<<endl;
cout<<"     El ID del cliente es: "<<contador+1<<endl;
 contador++;

system("pause");

}

}


}


void Cliente::consulta_uno()
{
    system("cls");
    cout<<"##############CONSULTA##############";
    string nombre_buscado;
    string apellido_buscado;
    cout<<"\nIngrese el nombre y apellido del cliente:";cin >> nombre_buscado>>apellido_buscado;

int i;
for( i=0; i<contador; i++ )
{
  if( nombre[i] == nombre_buscado && apellido[i] == apellido_buscado )
    break;
}

if( i < contador )
{
    system("cls");
cout<<"############USUARIO ENCONTRADO############"<<endl;
cout<<"SU ID ES:"<<i+1<<endl;
cout<<"SU NOMBRE Y APELLIDO ES:"<<nombre[i]<<" "<<apellido[i]<<endl;
cout<<"SU ESTATURA ES:"<<estatura[i]<<endl;
cout<<"Su estatus civil es:"<<situacion_civil[i]<<endl;
cout<<"La edad es: "<<edad[i];cout<<endl;
system("pause");    
  // Ya has encontrado el registro que buscas
  // ...


}
else
{
 //No esta en la lista
 cout<<"Este usuario no esta registrado...";
system("pause");

}

}

void Cliente::modificar()
{

    system("cls");
    cout<<"##############MODIFICAR##############";
    string nombre_buscado;
    string apellido_buscado;
    cout<<"\nIngrese el nombre y apellido del cliente:";cin >> nombre_buscado>>apellido_buscado;

int i;
for( i=0; i<contador; i++ )
{
  if( nombre[i] == nombre_buscado && apellido[i] == apellido_buscado )
    break;
}

if( i < contador )
{
    system("cls");
cout<<"############USUARIO ENCONTRADO############"<<endl;
cout<<"SU ID ES:"<<i+1<<endl;
cout<<"SU NOMBRE Y APELLIDO ES:"<<nombre[i]<<" "<<apellido[i]<<endl;
cout<<"SU ESTATURA ES:"<<estatura[i]<<endl;
cout<<"Su estatus civil es:"<<situacion_civil[i]<<endl;
cout<<"Su edad es:"<<edad[i]<<endl;
//MODIFICAR EL USUARIO
cout<<"###MODIFICAR###";
 cout<<"   Ingrese el nombre y apellido:";cin>>nombre[i]>>apellido[i];
 cout<<"   Ingrese la estatura:";cin>>estatura[i];
cout<<"    Ingrese la situacion civil del cliente :";cin>>situacion_civil[i];
cout<<"    Ingrese la edad:          ";cin>>edad[i];cout<<endl;

  // Ya has encontrado el registro que buscas
  // ...


}
else
{
 //No esta en la lista
 cout<<"Este usuario no esta registrado...";
system("pause");

}


}

 void Cliente::baja()
{
    system("cls");
    cout<<"#####BAJA#####";
    string nombre_buscado;
    string apellido_buscado;

    cout<<"\nIngrese el nombre y apellido del cliente:";cin >> nombre_buscado>>apellido_buscado;
int i,posicion;
char salir; //Para seleccionar en S/N



for( i=0; i<contador; i++ )
{
  if( nombre[i] == nombre_buscado && apellido[i] == apellido_buscado )
    break;
}

if( i < contador )
{



  // Ya has encontrado el registro que buscas
  // ...
  posicion=i;
  system("cls");
  cout<<"############USUARIO ENCONTRADO############"<<endl;
cout<<"SU ID ES:"<<i+1<<endl;
cout<<"SU NOMBRE Y APELLIDO ES:"<<nombre[i]<<" "<<apellido[i]<<endl;
cout<<"SU ESTATURA ES:"<<estatura[i]<<endl;
cout<<"Su estatus civil es:"<<situacion_civil[i]<<endl;
cout<<"Su edad es:"<<edad[i];cout<<endl;
cout<<"Desea realmente borrar este usuario? S/N:";cin>>salir;
if('s'==salir || 'S'==salir)
{

}
else
{
    cout<<"Cancelando...";
}


}
else
{
 //No esta en la lista


system("pause");

}

}





Cliente pt; //Declaro una variable de tipo Cliente para llamar los metodos.

int main()
{



}
```

Comment: Entonces, como sobrescribo sin afectar a mis arreglos?

Comment: char nombre[5][10]; //atributos de la clase
 char apellido[5][10];
  float estatura[5];
 int edad[5];
 char situacion_civil[5][10];
Esas son, no lo están.

Comment: Entonces los vuelvo null con 0?

Comment: Si me funciona la busqueda de cadenas.

Answer (score 1):

Esta clase tiene varios errores de concepto. No se si el propio enunciado te obliga a cometer esos errores o si los estás haciendo tu solo.

Lo primero es que no se concibe que una clase llamada `Cliente` realmente actue como si fuese una lista de clientes. Lo lógico, lo normal y lo esperable es que la clase `Cliente` únicamente se encargue de gestionar los datos de un cliente (para eso se llama `Cliente` y no `ListaClientes`), dejando la gestión de la lista a otra clase. Hacer esto simplifica el diseño y la gestión enormemente:

```
struct Cliente
{
  char nombre[10];          // es preferible std::string nombre
  char apellido[10];        // es preferible std::string apellido;
  float estatura;
  int edad;
  char situacion_civil[10]; // es preferible std::string situacion_civil
};
```

La gestión de la lista puede implementarse a mano o recurrir a los contenedores de la STL:

```
Cliente clientes[5]; //array con 5 clientes

std::vector<Cliente> clientes; //lista para un número indeterminado de clientes

class ListaClientes // clase personalizada para gestionar la lista
{
  // ...
};
```

Por otro lado fíjate que la variable `contador` no pertenece a la clase... esto hace que únicamente puedas tener una lista en todo tu programa. Prueba a crear dos listas y a llenar una con 5 elementos... y luego intenta utilizar la otra, verás que risa. Si esa variable sirve para gestionar la lista tiene que estar dentro de la clase, no fuera.

Salvo que el ejercicio te esté imponiendo el diseño actual yo te sugeriría que lo modificases a la mayor brevedad.

Dicho esto, tu estás implementando la lista como un array de elementos (bueno, realmente son 5 arrays... uno para cada atributo, una barbaridad). En base al diseño que tienes, para eliminar un elemento tienes que:

- Desplaza una posición hacia arriba los siguientes registros, de tal forma que el registro a borrar queda sobreescrito.
- Decrementas la variable `contador`.

Algo así:

```
// usando la STL
std::copy(&nombre[indice_a_borrar+1],&nombre[6],&nombre[indice_a_borrar]);
contador--;

// a mano
for( int i = indice_a_borrar+1; i<6; i++ )
  nombre[i-1] = nombre[i];
contador--;
```